# how get a random element boost unordered_map?

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map, unordered

i using typedef boost::unordered_map. how to get a random element
v: c++ 03

code:

```
member_1.insert(std::make_pair(gg, M2_NEW CGGList(gg)));

    typedef boost::unordered_map<CGG, CGGList*> Map1;
    Map1 member_1;
```

Comment: Generate random key to get random value.Using an iterator to iterate several times randomly

Answer (score 0):

You will not find an efficient method (wrong datastructure).

But you can always:

```
auto random_it = std::next(member1.begin(), my_random(member2.size()));
```

Where my_random would be implemented like `rand()%n` (bad) or using `std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t>` (much better).

Comment: auto ? i using c++ 03

Comment: So? Replace it with the proper types. I don't see the problem. I was answering the question, I'm not required to teach c++ or write complete solutions to unknown specs I think.

Comment: question is how to .. on 03